# programmatically navigation with setViewControllers

Tags: ios

I'm trying to use a Third Part Drop Down menu called Remenu, that can be found here https://github.com/romaonthego/REMenu

The menu is appearing but, when i try to click in an item i always get a black screen. I double checked everything, and i cannot find anything wrong, this is the 3 time, i'm trying to implement that plugin.

This is how i'm trying to Create a Button using Remenu:

```
REMenuItem *homeItem = [[REMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home"
                                                subtitle:@"Return to Home Screen"
                                                   image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon_Home"]
                                        highlightedImage:nil
                                                  action:^(REMenuItem *item) {
                                                      NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
                                                      ListasViewController *myList = [[ListasViewController alloc]init];
                                                      [self setViewControllers:@[myList]animated:NO];

                                                  }];
```

When i click on the button i get a black screen.

I'm not really sure where the problem is, so here is the whole zipped project https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37859830/newRemenutest.zip Anyhelp, will be immensely appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The black screen is showing up because value of `myList` is `nil`.

In **Storyboard**, getting instance of some `UIViewController` can be done using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method.

In this case, this should be like this:

```
ListasViewController *myList = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ListasViewController"];
```

But remember, you need to set the `Storyboard ID` of the ViewController itself!

[image]

[image]